# In function overloading the order of function call differs in function declaration in case of outside and inside the main function

Tags: c++

If we mention the function declaration outside the main(as commented in the code below) it is ok with it. But if I mention the function declaration inside the main as shown in the code below,then in runtime,whatever value (integer or floating type) is provided only the area with int as argument type is called,i.e. irrespective of the data type provided only one type of function (here area(int)) is called repeatedly.Why this happens,what is wrong with the function declaration, I want it to be clerified.Thanks in advance.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
  //void area(int);
  //void area(float);
void main()
{
  int a;
  float b;
  void area(int);
  void area(float);
  clrscr();
  cout<<"enter the length or breadth of square";
  cin>>a;
  area(a);
  cout<<"enter the radius of the circle";
  cin>>b;
  area(b);
  getch();
}
void area(int x)
{
  cout<<"area of square "<<x*x;
}
void area(float x)
{
  cout<<"\narea of circle "<<3.14*x*x;
}
```

Comment: Your compiler must be broken (it is ancient and non-standard if it compiles that code). Here's [an MCVE](http://ideone.com/AiaJ9Y).

Comment: @rosemary weird it works fine when i run it, calls the `area(int)` first then `area(float)` and yes the compiler im using isn't exactly up-to-standards :)

Comment: thank u both for the response

Comment: I find this kind of function overloading pretty confusing. I would name the functions `printSquareArea()` and `printCircleArea()`. And add `<< endl` to the end of `cout` lines, so they work as expected not only in this special case.

Comment: May I know which version you are using @juanchopanza

Comment: @rosemary Any standards compliant version will work. Try any gcc or clang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you described can occur in case when within main you declared only one function with the parameter of type `int`. For example

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

void area(int);
void area(float);

int main()
{
  int a;
  float b;

  void area(int);

  clrscr();

  cout<<"enter the length or breadth of square";
  cin>>a;
  area(a);
  cout<<"enter the radius of the circle";
  cin>>b;
  area(b);
  getch();
}

void area(int x)
{
  cout<<"area of square "<<x*x;
}
void area(float x)
{
  cout<<"\narea of circle "<<3.14*x*x;
}
```

In  this case only the function with the parameter of type `int` will be called because the local function declaration hides the function declarations in the global namespace.

Otherwise if the both functions are declared in main and only the function with the parameter of type int is called then the compiler has a bug.

Take into account that function main shall have return type `int` though some compilers allows to use type void. But such declarations of main is not C++ compliant.

Comment: I am using turbo c++ 3.0 and having that problem. Available in http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2012/11/download-turbo-c-for-windows-xp-for-free.html

Comment: @rosemary  Now there are many freely-available modern compilers. You should uodate your compiler.:)

Comment: @rosemary  A also use an old version MS VC++ 2010. Because I do not write programs in C++ (I am unemployeed) I do not need a modern compiler.:) But if I need then I always can use on-line modern compilers at www.ideone.com or at http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ or at http://melpon.org/wandbox/